# How I am able to fetch updated value from a Child widget using callback without Calling setState() in parent Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

In the code below I am using a callback to forward value from child to parent widget but I'm not calling setState() callback and yet I am able to print latest value? Can anyone Explain this because from My understanding a value is only updated when setState() is called.

Parent:

```
     class One extends StatefulWidget {
      const One({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _OneState createState() => _OneState();
    }

    class _OneState extends State<One> {
      String _text;

    //CallBack
      func(text) {
//No setState() is being called here.
        _text = text;
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print('Build One');
    
        return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Two(func: func),
                TextButton(
                  child: Text('Press Me'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print(_text);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Child:

```
class Two extends StatefulWidget {
  const Two({Key key, this.func}) : super(key: key);
  final Function func;

  @override
  _TwoState createState() => _TwoState();
}

class _TwoState extends State<Two> {
  String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Build Two');
    return TextField(
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          text = value;
        });
//Callback is being executed after the setState yet when i press button in Parent widget it prints latest value.
          widget.func(text);

      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setState updates the **variable changes in the UI** by rebuilding the widget.

Let's say you have a variable i = 0 in your code and on the press of a button this variable gets incremented i++.

```
int i = 0;

void increment(){
    i++;
}
```

if you have used this variable **i** in the UI, then the increment function will update the value of i but no changes will reflect on the UI.

In order to update the changes in the UI we use setState like this

```
void increment(){
    setState({
        i++;
    });
}
```